# How to publish JMS message concurrently in one connection

Tags: java, jms, wildfly-8, hornetq, jms-topic

I want know how to publish JMS message concurrently to different topic.

---

Example:
1 thread to publish JMS message to topic X,
1 thread to publish JMS message to topic Y periodically (let say every 5 seconds)

How can achieve that?

Currently using Wildfly 8.3 (Hornetq) as JMS provider.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to use Java's [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), e.g.:

```java
ScheduledExecutorService ses = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);
ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> sendJmsMessage(topicX), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> sendJmsMessage(topicY), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```